# MonoDroid Timer

Tags: android, timer, xamarin.android

If I set up a timer in the way that [this article](http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12) describes, I am unsure of a couple things.  I understand my 2nd question may or may not have a definite answer, so I will accept as the answer if my first question can be addressed.

1) If the timer is begun by one activity and is set to run every 5 minutes until told to stop, does that activity finishing or being sent to the background by the user changing activities affect it?  The one time I've used a timer seemed VERY intermittent and don't know if it is something I did wrong or just an inherent issue with timers.

2) I've seen a few people say that even android doesn't recommend using timers.  I've seen the recommendation for postDelayed(), but as explained in the article I referenced, for tasks that need to be repeated every X minutes, that can be problematic.  Is there a more preferable option that I am missing?

Basically, I am checking for connectivity to internet before syncing information back to the server.  If the device is not connected, I want to start a timer that checks for connectivity and attempts to run my Sync method every 5 or 10 minutes until successful at which point the timer can stop.  This timer needs to be able to start from any activity, continue running every 5 or 10 minutes regardless of what activity is currently being used and be cancel-able from any activity.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TinyIoC/TinyMessenger](http://hg.grumpydev.com/tinyioc/wiki/Home).

I do a similar thing to what you're describing by:

1. Defining messages for particular services.
2. Instantiating services which subscribe to messages they're interested in.
3. Subscribing to the service's messages when starting them.

If you kick off on a new thread, a service that implements a timer, you can start/stop/pause it from anywhere and you can receive any messages it broadcasts (completion/error etc.)

You just to have be careful that you explicitly run on the UI thread, if the callbacks need to write messages for the user.

When you stop the service, if you have a reference to the thread it runs on, you just broadcast the service's stop message and call join().

Hope that helps.